# IT-140 project II text based game

Tags: python

0

I have been working on my video game for my class project and we are using dictionaries in order to create a videogame story board. My current code allows me to move rooms just fine but I can add any item to my inventory.

```
rooms = {
    'Parking lot': {'South': 'Main entrance', 'North': 'dragon'},
    'Main entrance': {'North': 'Parking lot', 'South': 'Check in area', 'item': 'red star'},
    'Check in area': {'North': 'Main entrance', 'South': 'Main hallway', 'item': 'blue star'},
    'Main hallway': {'North': 'Check in area', 'South': 'Security area', 'item': 'green star'},
    'Security area': {'North': 'Main hallway', 'South': 'Gates hallway', 'item': 'yellow star'},
    'Gates hallway': {'North': 'Security area', 'West': 'Waiting area A', 'East': 'Waiting area B',
                      'item': 'orange star'},
    'Waiting area A': {'East': 'Gates hallway', 'item': 'purple star'},
    'Waiting area B': {'West': 'Gates hallway ', 'item': 'pink star'}
}


def welcome():
    print("Welcome to Magic Stars!!")
    print("There is a Dragon threatening to destroy your city, currently is in the airport.")
    print("you need to collect the 7 magic stars that are spread around the abandoned airport.")
    print("are you ready to start this adventure?")
    print('----------------------------------------')


welcome()

inventory = []

directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'exit', 'take']

current_room = 'Main entrance'

while True:
    print("You are in  {}".format(current_room))
    print('Your current inventory: {}'.format(inventory))
    print('In this room you see the  {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    command = input("Enter command:").split()[-1].capitalize()
    print('-----------------------------')

    if command == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'Exit'
        print("Thanks for Playing!!")
        break

    elif command in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
        # invalid move
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Add a `take` command. When the user enters that, do `inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])`